# Disable themes in outlook 2010 via registry

Tags: outlook, registry

I need to know if it is possible to force a user to use a particular theme (No theme) in Outlook 2010 and also restrict them from being able to change the theme..

There seems to be quite a lot of solutions for outlook 2007 on the internet but nothing for 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

You can read the current Office theme by looking at the value of HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common.